# Return large json response from a node express api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a controller in a node/express api that returns data to build a report. Depending on the report, the data can be very large (20Mb) for a request.

What's the best way to get this kind of data and keep a good user experience?

Don't want to use paging, I would have to do N requests until I get all the data. Thought about **chunked transfer encoding**, **web sockets** comes up to my mind but I'm not sure it's the best approach.

Thanks.

Comment: `Don't want to use paging`, but that would be the best user experience..

Comment: currently, it's getting all the data at once, which takes some time. I have paging so far, but I see paging as a user interaction, user would get new chunks of data when he wants. In this case, user needs all this data to build the report.

Comment: Maybe you should use AJAX in another process to fetch the data in chunks. In this way the user can continue to interact with the browser until all the data is downloaded and then you can display the report? Also make sure that you compress the data since JSON is in simple text format.

Comment: Paging does not necessarily need user interaction. But of course your clientside logic must implement fetching the remaining results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, user needs all this data to build the report.

No, the user needs *the report*. If you move the creation of that report to the backend, you only have to send the final report to the client which is probably more lightweight. It might also allow for serverside caching.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's no real alternative to pagination, though you can set up a simple script on the client-side that would load more data/pages when scrolled to the bottom of the page.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // your api ajax calls 
    }
};
```

Comment: and where is the difference to a paginated data here? :D

Comment: It **is** pagination, but it's loaded dynamically as the user scrolls down the page